# Does modifying read cache on my SD card also affect the speed of reading my Ext3 partition?

Tags: link2sd, ext3

I'm trying to make Link2SD work on my phone so I partitioned my 16gb SD to 4gb for the Ext3 partition and the rest for normal storage.

I'm noticing some slight lag on my usage of the phone and I read on [this article](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1010807) that I can in fact, increase the read cache to speed up reading contents on the SD. My question is; does increasing the read cache also affect the speed of reading my Ext3 partition? Or does it only affect the "normal" storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with normal disks, this should apply to the disk and not a specific partition. Some file systems offer additional caching, which then would apply to the specific partition -- but disk cache should always apply to the entire disk.